Weak closure of a subset of the unit sphere of $\ell_1$
It is a well-known and standard fact that for every infinite-dimensional Banach space $E$ the weak closure $\overline{S_E}^w$ of the unit sphere $S_E$ of $E$ is equal to the closed unit ball $B_E$ of $E$. Another similar fact asserts that for every infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$ its orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ converges weakly to $0$, that is, $\overline{\{e_n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}}^w=\{e_n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$.
Let's look at $\ell_1$.
Q: Are there any criteria (that is, sufficient or necessary conditions) when the weak closure $\overline{A}^w$ of a subset $A$ of the unit sphere $S_{\ell_1}$ contains $0$?
A simple sample criterion is given by the first sentence of this post, in fact it works for any infinite-dimensional Banach space: If $A$ is norm-dense in $S_{\ell_1}$, then $0\in\overline{A}^w$.

Although the weak topology is never metrizable in infinite dimensional Banach space, we still have the peculiar fact that in $\ell_1$, if $x_n$ tends weakly to $x$, then it already tends to $x$ in the norm, so the sequential weak closure of the unit sphere does not contain zero.

Yes, the Schur property of $\ell_1$. So, the unit sphere $S_{\ell_1}$ is weakly sequentially closed and the norm topology and the weak topology have the same compact sets. Therefore, for no weakly compact set $A\subseteq S_{\ell_1}$ we have $0\in\overline{A}^w$.
